# Java FX Swing node reduces the overall size of the swing components visually

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-8

I have a swing frame which looks like this actually

[image]

But when i wrap that in a javafx swing node the overall size of the component reduces noticeably giving me this:

[image]

I can see the font size, table size everything looks zoomed out.

I want the same look and feel in the latter also. Please help.

Thanks,
Hari

Comment: Your images look the same to me.

Comment: If you don't like the look, dont wrap it. This is probably due to Windows scaling the window.

Comment: The image is looking same probably because i have taken screenshot of only the window. but the fact is the font size and the component sizes have decreased.

Comment: @harikrishna that is strange, can you make a test case that demonstrates your issue. Eg. a JPane with a JLabel + JTextField, wrap that and displayed vs javafx?

Comment: what @matt is suggestion is a [mcve] :)

Comment: Hi matt and kleopatra, Yes it looks strange the font is reduced  in javafx. i did create a simple application with a jpanel and jtextfield. i have a javafx textfield below it and i  see lot of differences between both. So i ended up increasing the font globally of the swing app using UIManager and made it look alike. 

Thanks for the suggestions:)

Answer (score 0):

After so much of toiling around i saw theres no solution to this so i just increased the font sizes of the whole swing application using UIManager api's.